# How to pass double quoted parameter to Python requests.get()

Tags: python, string, https, python-requests, urlencode

An API I'm using requires one of the parameters to be passed in in double quotes like so: `https://example.com/api?country="US"`. It seems no matter how I try to pass this in, I get a 500 response using Python's `requests` library. I've tried the following:

- `params = {"country": '"US"'}
- `params = {"country": ""US""}

  - these lead to the URL not picking up the argument in quotation marks.
- `params = urlencode({"country": '"US"'})` which gives the string `country=%22US%22`.

  - If I paste the URL with that string into my browser I get the correct result, but running `requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)` using the urlencoded params, I still get a 500 error.

I know the API is working as I can test it in my browser, the problem lies in sending over a correctly formatted URL.

Is there something I'm missing here regarding how to pass in this double quoted argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, what you did using `urlencoded` is correct, or either way you can actually use directly the single close values in the parameter such as

```py
resp = requests.get("https://example.com/api", params={"country": '"US"'})
```

But i'm not so sure why the response still gives you a 500 error. Or it could be there is missing additional information when you request the related API?